# Reentrant script execution -?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, w3c

From https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/dom.html#dom-tree-accessors

> document.currentScript
>   Returns the script element that is currently executing. In the case of **reentrant script execution**, returns the one that most recently started executing amongst those that have not yet finished executing.

What is the reentrant script execution in HTML 5?

Comment: Very interesting question!

Comment: @trincot - see my answer for a demo of reentrant script execution.

Comment: @Alohci, I don't think that is an example of a reentrant script. See my comment to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>test case</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="script1.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

script1.js

```
document.write("<p>script 1 entered");
document.write("<p>1a:" + document.currentScript.src);
document.write("<script src='script2.js'></script>");
document.write("<p>1b:" + document.currentScript.src);
document.write("<p>script 1 exited");
```

script2,js

```
document.write("<p>script 2 entered");
document.write("<p>2:" + document.currentScript.src);
document.write("<p>script 2 exited");
```

If you browse to such a page, it will show

```
script 1 entered

1a:{path.to}/script1.js

script 2 entered

2:{path.to}/script2.js

script 2 exited

1b:{path.to}/script1.js

script 1 exited
```

That's re-entrant script execution, and you can see that the currentScript is script1.js, then script2.js and then back to script1.js again after script2.js exits.

There's a working version at http://alohci.net/static/reentrant/test.htm

Comment: This is not re-entrance. This is just continuation of the script. True reentrance is (from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrancy_%28computing%29)): *"if [code] can be interrupted in the middle of its execution, and then be safely called again ("re-entered") before its previous invocations complete execution."*. This is not the case in your example. The script is never *called again*. It just resumes execution.

Comment: @trincot - It's not the individual script that is re-entrant, it's *script execution* that's re-entrant. i.e. Script1 writes to the input stream - the parser reads from the input stream, sees the script element and launches a new *script execution* to run script2.

Comment: Indeed, your example illustrates a new *script execution*, not a *reentrant script execution*.

Comment: But that new script execution is running while the script1 script execution is running, so script execution must have been re-entered.

Comment: But that is not the definition of reentrance. What you describe is a different concept.

Comment: It would be reentrance if script 1 was running, and script 1 was reentered from the top again (possibly via script 2, but that is irrelevant).

Comment: Again, the re-entrance is not about the individual scripts. It's about the context/environment in which scripts are run.

Comment: At this point I think it is best to conclude and say "we agree to differ" ;-)

Comment: OK. I don't think either of us is going to convince the other.

Answer (score 0):

`document.currentScript` can be used when the contents of an external script may want to reference its own SCRIPT tag.

It is mainly used when you want to parameterization your script using some options on the SCRIPT tag which can potentially help simplify configurations.

Below an example, in this case we want to configure `require.js` to load as first module `js/main`. `document.currentScript` allows you to get the `data-main` attribute .

```
<script src="scripts/require.js" data-main="js/main"></script>
```

[More information with example can be found here](http://www.2ality.com/2014/05/current-script.html).

Comment: This explains the `document.currentScript` property, but the question was about *reentrant script execution*.

Answer (score 0):

reentrant script is nothing but an external script tag which call itself (like recursive) (or calls some other files which again calls the same script)

Example:-

my_lovely_script.js

```
$.getScript("my_lovely_script.js", function(){

   alert("Script loaded but not necessarily executed.");

});
```

inthese cases the document.currentScript will return the one that most recently started executing amongst those that have not yet finished executing

Comment: Can you give an example of how a script element is *called*?

Comment: I have added the example

Comment: Have you tested that? This does not execute the `script` tag. Instead jQuery loads the script from its source in a variable and evaluates it. It reports `document.currentScript` as `null`, which is not the re-entrant situation described in the question. So how can a `script` element be called?

Comment: include this script like
<script src="my_lovely_script.js"></script>
in yout html. and my_lovely_script.js content is shown as above
try this... it will workout

Comment: Yes, that is the way to execute the `script` element the first time, but how to execute it a second time? If you include it again, it will be seen as a different `script` element. This would not be re-entrant code. The question is: how can you execute the same `script` element content twice, in a re-entrant way.